# python line break by 10 elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, line-breaks

So I have to write to the standard output 100 number but in a line only put 10 number, I write the code it is almost perfect but the output is like:

```
23456789101
5378566145 
8353464573 
7596745634 
4352362356 
2342345346 
2553463221 
9873422358 
8223552233 
578942378
```

and there is the code:

```
import sys
import random as r

UPTO = 100

def main():
    for i in xrange(UPTO):
        if i % 10 == 0 and i != 0:
            sys.stdout.write(str(r.randint(0, 9)) + '\n')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(str(r.randint(0, 9))) 
    print
```

how can I do this perfectly?

Comment: How do you define "perfectly"?  Can you give the output that you expect?

Comment: in every line should be 10 number but my output's first line there is 11 and last line there is 9 the other lines are good

Comment: The code there shouldn't run, there's no left operand to that modulo operator in your if statement

Comment: `if % 10 == 0`? Can you fix your paste?

Comment: @KingstonJoshua: Put the code in the question itself properly formatted.  You can use the [edit] link.

Comment: I fixed it the left operand is i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start at 1 and go to `UPTO + 1`:

```
for i in xrange(1, UPTO + 1):
```

Once you change that your code works:

```
In [18]: main()
3989867912
0729456107
3457245171
4564003409
3400380373
1638374598
5290288898
6348789359
4628854868
4172212396
```

You can also use print as a function with an import from `__future__` to simplify your code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import random as r

UPTO = 100

def main():
    # use a step of 10
    for i in range(0, UPTO, 10):
        # sep="" will leave no spaces between, end="" removes newline
        print(*(r.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(10)), end="", sep="")
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop in:

```
for i in xrange(1, UPTO + 1):
```

Code:

```
import sys
import random as r

UPTO = 100

def main():
    for i in xrange(1, UPTO + 1):
        if i % 10 == 0 and i != 0:
            sys.stdout.write(str(r.randint(0, 9)) + '\n')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(str(r.randint(0, 9))) 
    print
main()
```

Output:

```
5324707535
0662651201
6774603548
2062356640
2371234722
0295841132
5498111577
0871557117
3062255375
2219008944
```

Answer (score 1):

I would import the `print` from python3 and use that:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

UPTO = 100
for i in xrange(100):
    for j in xrange(10):
        print(random.randint(0,9), end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Or just stop using python2 like the rest of us have! :) Good work on the most functional answer (including mine!)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your existing code is, as others have noted, just a matter of starting at 1, not 0 (or adding 1 to `i` when testing the remainder).

But you don't need to reinvent the wheel at all. You can simplify automatic wrapping a lot with [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html). Just generate the output data all at once, e.g.:

```
digits = 100
# Make a 100 long string of digits
alltext = ''.join(str(random.randrange(10)) for _ in range(digits))

# Or to achieve the same effect more efficiently:
alltext = str(random.randrange(10**(digits-1), 10**digits))
```

then use `textwrap.wrap` and a loop to `print` it:

```
import textwrap

for line in textwrap.wrap(alltext, width=10):
    print line
```

Which gets (for example):

```
4961561591
3969872520
1896401684
8608153539
0210068022
3975577783
8321168859
8214023841
8138934528
7739266079
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is working for me: for i in range(1, UPTO + 1): !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use of the `itertools` `grouper` recipe.

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=""):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

UPTO = 100

digits = [str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(UPTO)]

sys.stdout.write("\n".join(map("".join, grouper(digits, 10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For python2

```
from random import randint
import sys
for i in range(100):
  sys.stdout.write(str(randint(0,9))+("\n" if i%10==9 else ""))
```

or if you allow the "print" function instead of the print statement

```
from __future__ import print_function
from random import randint
for i in range(100):
  print(randint(0,9), end="\n" if i%10==9 else "")
```